# Unable to parsing got Null pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-emulator

```
et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        String name = Double.toString(area);
        et2.setText(name);

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

01-31 19:05:01.346: D/AndroidRuntime(650): Shutting down VM
01-31 19:05:01.346: W/dalvikvm(650): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zlistactivity/com.example.zlistactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:356)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at com.example.zlistactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-31 19:05:01.366: E/AndroidRuntime(650):  ... 11 more
01-31 19:05:05.156: I/Process(650): Sending signal. PID: 650 SIG: 9

Comment: I can't see a NPE in the log. I can see a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` which is `Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format` see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html). I suggest checking your inputs as something is not what you are expecting it to be.

Comment: @andy parse to string is in correct format only..

Comment: The _exact_ line number and file where the error occurred is in the stacktrace -  `com.example.zlistactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)` - what is on that line?

Comment: @andy radius = Double.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());

Comment: Java is telling you that it cannot convert `et1.getText().toString()` to a Double. Are you sure that the String being returned only contains characters that can be represented in a Double? See [`Double.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: Also note that `""` cannot be parsed as a double.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your edittext before the Textchange listener :

> ```
> et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
> et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
> @Override
> public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
>     String name = Double.toString(area);
>     et2.setText(name);
> }
> ```